# How to Display Current Month's Calendar Starting With Today's Date in React JS Full Calender

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to display today's date at starting date for current month's calender used @fullcalendar/react plugin for that. please review attachment.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPO77.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out how to do this natively

You can make this dynamic by using the following logic

```
const unixTime = Date.now();
console.log(unixTime) // UNIX Epoch Timestamp
const date = new Date(unixTime);
const currentDOW = date.getDay();
// if you console.log currentDOW it outputs 3 --> Wednesday
```

[image: from the fullcalendar docs] it appears that the DOW (day of week) defaults to 0 (sunday). So, you should be able to dynamically set the first box rendered to the `currentDOW` value returned (0-6, or Sunday-Saturday) to have the current firstDay updated daily.

Comment: May I know where I have to write this code means any callback function of fullcalender plugin? @andrew-ross

Comment: I believe so, based on the documentation. The `getDay` value will update each day if you use the `currentDOW` const which returns a number corresponding to whatever day it is for the timezone the app is deployed in

Comment: I tried above logic but it's not displaying proper. please review this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/13fr71o
https://prnt.sc/13fr9nm

Comment: any other alernative way? @andrew-ross